# bigquery pandas df on datalab

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I want to use pandas to pull from bigquery in datalab. However, something doesn't work. I'm using Python 2.7

```
query = "select * from myTable"

df_train = pd.read_gbq(project_id='my_project', query=query, dialect='standard'
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: pandas requires google-cloud-python for Google BigQuery support: cannot import name make_exception
```

How can I use pandas?

Answer (score 1):

The docs [say you need](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_gbq.html#pandas.read_gbq) `pandas-gbq` to get this done, and that you need to have some auth happening somewhere. Install `pandas-gbq` with `pip install pandas-gbq` or `conda install pandas-gbq` to address the error you pasted, and also ensure auth is happening either by passing a `private_key` arg to `read_gbq` or by setting the defaults as described in the docs.